# Getting list of databases from IndexedDB takes long (up to 1 min)

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, indexeddb, dexie

When I request a list of databases from IndexedDB, like this:

`await indexedDB.databases();`

usially it takes a few millisecons to complete, **but sometimes it takes up to 1 minute**.

Based on the Chrome Performance Profiling, during the minute nothing is happening, see the empty part in the middle in the image below

[image]

IndexedDB doesn't process any complex stuff during this time either.

I can reproduce it on Chrome (Mac, Windows).
I wasn't able to reproduce it on FF.

Some details that may be relevant:

- this call is a part of a complex PWA application. There is a service worker and some web workers;
- I use Dexie to work with IndexedDB;

Any advice on what can cause the delay?
Or maybe some ideas how to debug it?